# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' undefined' to data type int

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' undefined' to data type int" from my stored procedure.This is getting called from WCF service. 
Below is the sample format of my stored procedure.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_GetLang]
(
@UserID nchar(10),
@Return nchar(10)='' output
)AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @Return = vc_LanguageName 
FROM [dbo].[vc_UserPrefrences] person INNER JOIN
[dbo].[vc_Languages] lang on person.vc_LanguagID = lang.vc_LanguageID
WHERE person.vc_UserID = @UserID
END
```

Here only person.vc_UserID and vc_languageid are integers.

Can you please suggest some solutions if you aware.

Thank you!

Comment: _Here only person.vc_UserID and vc_languageid are integers_ Then why do you define them as a `nchar` in your SP definition? Always **always** choose the right data type https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 0):

You should change `@UserID nchar(10)` to `@UserID INT`.

Answer (score 0):

You could `CAST` `vc_UserID` to `NCHAR` in following:

```
WHERE CAST(person.vc_UserID AS NCHAR(10)) = @UserID
```

Or change datatype of variable `@UserID` to `INT`